# match column1-5 in both files and print matching column1-5 along with column6&7 of file1 and column6 of file2

Tags: text-processing, awk, perl

want to match column 1-5 in 2 files and print column1-5 along with column 6&7 from file1 and column6 from file2. Non-matching rows from both file should also get printed with NA value in non-matching columns

`file1`

```
12  800000  900000  66  73  0   0  
12  900000  1000000 73  48  2   2  
13  1000000 1100000 11  11  0   0  
12  1100000 1200000 12  12  0   0  
18  1400000 1600000 33  33  3   3
```

`file2`

```
12  800000  900000  66  73  145(28.12)  
12  900000  1000000 73  48  703(51.17)  
13  1000000 1100000 11  11  545(43.99)  
12  1100000 1200000 12  12  699(45.30)
14  16100000    16200000    0   0   11(14.50)  
14  16200000    16300000    0   0   0
```

`Expected output`

```
12  800000  900000  66  73  145(28.12)  0  0   
12  900000  1000000 73  48  703(51.17)  2  2  
13  1000000 1100000 11  11  545(43.99)  0  0  
12  1100000 1200000 12  12  699(45.30)  0  0  
14  16100000  16200000  0  0  11(14.50)  NA  NA 
14  16200000  16300000  0  0  0  NA  NA  
18  1400000 1600000 33  33  NA  3   3
```

I tried below awk command but not getting columns from both files

```
awk 'FNR==NR{A[$1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4 FS $5]=$3;next}{print ($1 FS $3 FS $4 FS $5 in A ) ? $0 OFS A[$1 FS $3 FS $4 FS $5] : $0 OFS "NA"}' file1 file2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code doesn't match your description, e.g. it's storing $3 from file1 to print later but you say you want to print $4 and $6, and then your expected output doesn't match either of those and shows $6 and $7 from file1 instead. So, just going by your expected output, I think this is what you want:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ key = $1 OFS $2 OFS $3 OFS $4 OFS $5 }
FNR==NR {
    file1[key] = $6 OFS $7
    next
}
{
    print $0, (key in file1 ? file1[key] : "NA" OFS "NA")
    delete file1[key]
}
END {
    for ( key in file1 ) {
        print key, "NA", file1[key]
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
12  800000  900000  66  73  145(28.12) 0 0
12  900000  1000000 73  48  703(51.17) 2 2
13  1000000 1100000 11  11  545(43.99) 0 0
12  1100000 1200000 12  12  699(45.30) 0 0
14  16100000    16200000    0   0   11(14.50) NA NA
14  16200000    16300000    0   0   0 NA NA
18 1400000 1600000 33 33 NA 3 3
```

Note the use of a variable to hold the key index for both files. When you have a key that's a combination of values, don't try to write it multiple times in your code as it's easy to get that wrong as you did where you forgot to include `$2` in the lookup of the map when processing file2 (you used `$1 FS $3 FS $4 FS $5 in A` instead of `$1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4 FS $5 in A` and did the same again in `A[$1 FS $3 FS $4 FS $5]`).

Also - don't use all upper case variable names (e.g. `A`) to avoid clashing with builtin variable names, and use parentheses to make your code clearer if nothing else, e.g. idk if `$1 FS $2 in A` means `($1 FS) ($2 in A)` (i.e. the concatenation of `$1 FS` with the result of looking up `$2 in A`) or `($1 FS $2) in A` (i.e. the result of looking up the concatenation of `$1 FS $2` in `A`) or something else but if you simply write it as `($1 FS $2) in A` then it's clear and unambiguous.

Finally note that I used `OFS` instead of `FS` as the array index separator - that's because in the code we are printing that value in the `END` section and the thing that should separate output fields is `OFS`, not `FS`. In this case they are both the same thing, a blank char, so you won't see a difference but if you wanted to output CSV instead then with my code all you need to do is add `-v OFS=','` and it'd work as-is whereas if you used `FS` between the array index subscripts then you'd need to change that.